# Creating callback functions dynamically for a set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

The variable `myCollection` holds `jQuery` DOM elements, and I want to set a `callback` function for each of their `onclick` event as shows below. Actually what I want is, to incrementally set or could say "burn" the `number` for each element, so when they are getting clicked, its own number would get alerted. This code alerts the last value of `number` when it was incremented in the loop the last time.

```
var number = 1;

myCollection.each(function(){
    this.onclick = function() { someFunction(number) };
    number++;
});

//This function is somewhere else, but accessible.
function someFunction(number) {
    alert(number);
}
```

How can I copy or instantiate callback functions for each elements, so they would have the same process but with different arguments bind to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic scoping problem, it can be solved like this:

```
myCollection.each(function(){
  this.onclick=(function(number) {
      // in this scope, number has been "burned"
      return function() {
          someFunction(number)
      };
  }(number));
  number++;
});
```

Note that jQuery already includes a correctly scoped index inside the each callback, so all you need to do is:

```
myCollection.each(function(i){
    $(this).click(function(){
        someFunction(i+1);
    });
});
```

Comment: David, could you please describe your first solution, why and how does it work? If you could just add a link or Q&A it would be nice of you too! Does this connected to closures? Thanks for your help!